# How to Retrieve product id from bar code?

Tags: android

I have used bar code scanner application and my activity will open a bar code scanner and it will successfully read the bar code.

But how do I retrieve/fetch that bar code value/product id from it??

Because my application just redirects it into google for search of that product. I have used Zxing for it.

Regards,
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

**com.google.zxing.client.android->CaputreAcitvity.java->handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode)** Where you will find rawResult Result variable in this variable result is stored. Put Toast there and print value of rawResult varibale.
Don't forget to convert rawResult into String.